# Magento 2: It is not recommended to specify supported PHP versions in dependencies

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

It is not recommended to specify supported PHP versions in dependencies. If specified, it must at least match the PHP requirements of the supported Magento versions.

Comment: what you want to ask please elaborate in detail

Comment: Basically i am working on extension development .when i validate it by market-place tool ,terminal show this type of message ?

Comment: you specified the php vesion in dependencies?

Comment: this is my composer.json file code
{
  "name": "esparksinc/extension",
  "description": "N/A",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "require": {
      "php": "~7.0.13|~7.1.0|7.2.*",
    "magento/framework": "101.0.*|102.0.*"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Esparksinc\\Extension\\": ""
    }
  }
}

Comment: I think you dont need to mention php version here

Comment: does it is not necessary?

Comment: yes it is not necessary